# Performance degradation after updating from CefSharp 92 to CefSharp 94+

Tags: windows, chromium, cefsharp

Upgrade from 92.0.260 to 94.4.110 (I've also tried as recent as 99 with similar behavior)
WinForms
x86

Our CefSharp based application is significantly more laggy after this update. This is most evident with hover and click events reacting slowly, and sluggishness when rendering CefSharp popup window instances. The issue is present with all Cef Settings being exactly the same.

These are the Cef initialization settings in use:

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--disable-features", "FormControlsRefresh,IntensiveWakeUpThrottling");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("v8-cache-options", "code");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-touch-adjustment", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("plugin-policy", "block");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Remove("disable-site-isolation-trials");

settings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true;
settings.ExternalMessagePump = false;
settings.JavascriptFlags = "--expose-gc --allow-natives-syntax";
```

And based on an environment variable:

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");
```

What are some possible causes for this sluggishness?

[Default CefSharp 94.4.110 Features Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bcfk.png)

Comment: Have you tested different hardware? How does the minimal example behave on the same machine? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: I'd suggest removing all your custom command line args also and see how it performs. Load chrome://Version in the browser and see what features CEF has disabled by default.

Comment: I've added the chrome://Version information

Comment: @amaitland. are there any good web pages to try using that may make performance issues more visible?

Comment: Add the features that are disabled by default to your list. https://www.google.com/doodles is quite busy, or just plain old YouTube home page has lots of content. It's also worth checking the log file for errors. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: The issue ended up being related to the build flags I was using to build CEF (we build it ourselves to enable H.264 video). It turns out that it was important to specify is_component_build or is_official_build for performance to be at acceptable levels, and we'd stopped specifying in the low 90s due to some issue with the build. As far as performance testing, I found this tool to be helpful: https://browserbench.org/Speedometer2.0/ which produced much worse results for the browser builds I observed degraded performance in.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md#markdown-header-windows-configuration for official release flags. Component builds are only for debugging and not for distribution.